# Error while building android ndk sample project

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-ndk

hello i am beginner in developing ndk apps.

I was going to build [sample application](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html#samples) but i got following errors while Compiling the native code using the ndk-build command.

I am using **UBUNTU** OS.

```
nidhi@php-pc1:~/android-sdk-linux_x86/android-ndk-r7/samples/hello-jni$ /home/nidhi/android-sdk-linux_x86/android-ndk-r7/ndk-build
Gdbserver      : [arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3] libs/armeabi/gdbserver
Gdbsetup       : libs/armeabi/gdb.setup
Compile thumb  : hello-jni <= hello-jni.c
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/hello-jni/hello-jni.o] Error 1
```

please help me to solve..

Edit:

i solve this by set PATH

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.5.2

but new error occur

`

```
android-sdk-linux_x86/android-ndk-r7/samples/hello-jni$ /home/nidhi/android-sdk-linux_x86/android-ndk-r7/ndk-build
Gdbserver      : [arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3] libs/armeabi/gdbserver
Gdbsetup       : libs/armeabi/gdb.setup
Compile thumb  : hello-jni <= hello-jni.c
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-mbionic"
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-mthumb"
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-mfpu=vfp"
jni/hello-jni.c:1:0: error: bad value (armv5te) for -march= switch
jni/hello-jni.c:1:0: error: bad value (xscale) for -mtune= switch
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/hello-jni/hello-jni.o] Error 1
```

pls help .

Edit :

it solve by set Cross complier PATH

export CROSS_COMPILER=$PATH:/home/nidhi/android-sdk-linux_x86/android-ndk-r7/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/

Comment: I have a feeling you're missing some more compiler flags. Can you post your Android.mk and Application.mk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it solve by set Cross complier PATH

```
export CROSS_COMPILER=$PATH:/home/nidhi/android-sdk-linux_x86/android-ndk-r7/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/
```

Comment: hey i had a same problem while compiling bambuser's ffmpeg for android on ubuntu 11.10. can u help me out?  see the question i have posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525578/bambuser-ffmpeg-arm-linux-androideabi-gcc-is-unable-to-create-an-executable-f