# Android ndk-r8 "error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory"

Tags: android, android-ndk, osx-mountain-lion

I am trying to use the Android NDK on Mountain Lion to build a library for Android, following this guide

http://masl.cis.gvsu.edu/2012/01/25/android-echoprint/

When it comes time to compile the library, I run:

```
cd <path to jni>
<ndk>/ndk-build
```

I get the following error:

```
Compile++ thumb  : echoprint-jni <= AndroidCodegen.cpp
arm-linux-androideabi-g++: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory
make: *** [/Users/wingdom/Desktop/obj/local/armeabi/objs/echoprint-jni/AndroidCodegen.o] Error 1
```

I believe I have added everything I need to to my path variable:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:Developer/android-sdk/tools:/Developer/android-sdk/platform-tools:/Developer/android-ndk:/Developer/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin
```

What else do I need to do in order to get this to compile? I am using the r8b NDK currently, but have tried it with versions all the way back to 6.

EDIT:

I tried this solution: [Error while building android ndk sample project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8544977/error-while-building-android-ndk-sample-project)

adding

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.5.2
```

to my path gets me this error:

```
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-mbionic"
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-mthumb"
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-mfpu=vfp"
/Users/wingdom/Desktop/jni/AndroidCodegen.cpp:1: error: bad value (armv5te) for -march= switch
/Users/wingdom/Desktop/jni/AndroidCodegen.cpp:1: error: bad value (xscale) for -mtune= switch
make: *** [/Users/wingdom/Desktop/obj/local/armeabi/objs/echoprint-jni/AndroidCodegen.o] Error 1
```

but adding

```
export CROSS_COMPILER=$PATH:/Developer/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin
```

doesn't help, like it did in the link above.

Comment: Not sure if that helps: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=345201 missing g++ on your system maybe?

Comment: Everything Ive read says g++ is installed when you install x-code, which I have installed. If I need to install it separately, how do I do it? Everything I have seen uses apt-get for linux.

Comment: when I just run "g++" on the command line, I get "i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2: no input files" so g++ is installed.

Comment: Is it a typo, or the problem? cd <path to jni> **/..**;
<path to **ndk** >/ndk-build

Comment: its a typo, I am running ndk-build from my projects directory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have experienced same error.
I was not able to execute even 'gcc, g++' command. So I have googled a lot to find solution, but nothing helped for me.

Then, I found that some filename in ndk is not correct, with tailing `_` on some filename.. (In my case, in toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86/arm-linux-androideabi/bin folder, there are `gcc_`, `g++_`, `c++_` instead of `gcc`, `g++`, `c++`.)
I used The unarchiver to extract NDK archive, so I think there are something wrong with unarchiving procedure.

So I re-downloaded NDK and checked MD5 checksum, then extracted archive using Mac's default archive utility.

Now, the problem has solved.

Comment: I will test it in a little bit when I get the time. I hope you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a bad download/unpack of the NDK.  The `cc1plus` binary that it's looking for should be in `$NDK_HOME/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/darwin-x86/libexec/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/`.  If it's not there, try re-downloading the SDK and/or unpacking it again.

If it *is* there, be sure to build passing `V=1` to `ndk-build`, and see if there are any odd `-B` options passed to the compiler.  The `-B` option tells `gcc` where to find its "sub-programs" (of which `cc1plus` is one).  Pretty sure there shouldn't be any on the command lines for r8, so if there are, something somewhere is passing bad flags.  For example, on my system, a C++ NDK command line ends up looking something like this:

```
 /opt/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -MMD -MP -MF ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/sometarget/SomeCppFile.o.d -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -D__ARM_ARCH_5__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5T__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5E__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5TE__  -Wno-psabi -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -mthumb -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 -I/opt/android-ndk/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport -I/opt/android-ndk/sources/cxx-stl//gabi++/include -DANDROID -Wall -Wa,--noexecstack  -frtti  -O2 -DNDEBUG -g   -I/opt/android-ndk/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include -c  jni/SomeCppFile.cpp -o ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/sometarget/SomeCppFile.o
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to install the g++:

`$sudo apt-get install g++`

Answer (score 0):

I have spent about a day to find root cause of this

```
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file...
```

and others issues.

The issues were that I unpacked NDK and SDK with 7z which removed executable permission for all binaries and Eclipse was not able to start cc1.
Once I unpacked tar files of SDK and NDK using tar, everything started working well.