# Bambuser ffmpeg - "arm-linux-androideabi-gcc is unable to create an executable file."

Tags: android, gcc, ffmpeg, ubuntu-11.10, android-ndk-r5

I know this may be possible duplicate of some questions. but answers for those threads are not helping me.

I am trying to compile ffmpeg library for android using Bambuser's ffmpeg.
I downloaded [Archive for client versions 1.3.7 to 1.6.0.](http://bambuser.com/r/opensource/ffmpeg-4f7d2fe-android-2011-03-07.tar.gz)  from bambuser.

I followed instruction given in REAME.
While running ./build.sh i came across following error

```
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc is unable to create an executable file.
C compiler test failed.

If you think configure made a mistake, make sure you are using the latest
version from SVN.  If the latest version fails, report the problem to the
ffmpeg-user@mplayerhq.hu mailing list or IRC #ffmpeg on irc.freenode.net.
Include the log file "config.log" produced by configure as this will help
solving the problem.
```

Here are last few lines of  **config.log** of ffmpeg

```
mktemp is /bin/mktemp
check_ld
check_cc
BEGIN /tmp/ffconf.qflVj27Q.c
    1   int main(void){ return 0; }
END /tmp/ffconf.qflVj27Q.c
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/home/chaitanya/android/android-ndk-r5b/platforms/android-8/arch-arm -c -o /tmp/ffconf.gc6um0Ki.o /tmp/ffconf.qflVj27Q.c
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory
C compiler test failed.
```

in **tmp** i do not find any relative folder or file as per config.log says "ffconf.qflVj27Q.c".

I am doing this on 
 1. Ubuntu 11.10  
 2. OpenJDK 6 
 3. android-ndk-r5b

**NOte**: 
I only have API-10 Installed in eclipse. (if it matters :D)

What could be the solution for this?

Comment: Found a solution yet?

Comment: facing same problem in windows

Comment: @AZone Did you find solution in windows?

Answer (score 11):

I finally found the problem with my setup when facing this same issue... Looking at the arm-build.sh script, I started following the script. Notice the "TOOLCHAIN=..." path.

Originally the path was: 
TOOLCHAIN=`echo $NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/*-x86`

When I went to verify this path exists, I noticed that it did not. 
I think the reason is that I have a **64-bit** build.

My path is actually:
.../toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64

What I ended up doing was copying the folder, and renaming it to "linux-x86" and now all is compiling.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: It is help me) Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible to edit build.sh file (change *-x86 to *-x86_64) instead?

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this problem this morning and tried solutions suggested for similar questions here. But none of the solutions worked for me.

But finally i solved it. In my case, it was problem with Android NDK package. My system is 64bit ubuntu and my ndk pkg was also linux-64bit. But when i used the ndk-linux-x86, this problem was solved. I hope that this might help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I meet similar problem when cross compile FFmpeg.

```
    --extra-cflags="-arm -std=gnu99 -fPIC" \
    --extra-ldflags="-arm" \
```

switched to

```
    --extra-cflags="-std=gnu99 -fPIC" \
```

solves my problem.